# transformClassesWithDexForDebug fails with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I'm compiling multidex project and gradle gives me this:

```
Execution failed for task ':Project:transformClassesWithDexForLiteDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

I suppose it happens because gradle runs out of memory and there are solutions to add:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

But in my case I get another error from gradle: `Cannot resolve symbol 'javaMaxHeapSize'`.

And it just does not compile.
Any help very appresciated!

Comment: Where is the dexOptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, if you have this kind of error, it is because you misplaced this `dexOptions`:

What you have to do is to put it as a child of `android` in your module (I guess called `app`) gradle file.

Like this:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {

    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Lolo

        }
        debug{

        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```